# Unexpected Amplifier Warm Up

Tags: audio, signal-processing, power-amplifier

The following diagram shows the signal processing stage of an audio system that I've recently implemented on a perfboard.

[image: The schematic]

The images of the circuit board are given below:

[image: The Circuit Board (Front)]

[image: The Circuit Board (Back)]

The circuit starts with a buffer which filters out possible DC component inside the input signal. Afterwards, a second-order Linkwitz-Riley crossover network comes into play which divides the low and medium-high frequency signals at approximately 500 Hz. Then, those two signal branches are fed into the amplifiers which are based upon bridge-configurated TDA2822Ms. Finally, the outputs drive two loudspeakers (a woofer and a tweeter).

When I energise the circuit and feed an audio signal, both amplifiers heat up aggressively whilst those two potentiometers aren't even halfway through. Additionally, even though I decrease the supply voltage down to +/-3V, those amplifiers still get very hot. Moreover, as I turn the pots, I can't get sounds out of the speakers at all (I've tested the circuit in a lab. There, I used a waveform generator and as I changed the frequency of it, I've easily noticed the change in pitch on the loudspekers, but the sound intensity was so low that my ear has had to be so close to the cone of the speaker.)

Of course, in general, amplifiers are prone to high amounts of power dissipation which in turn cause high temperature rise in them. However, this is an intriguing case for me as this is not the first time that I am building up an audio system which utilises TDA2822Ms. My desktop loudspeaker system uses one of those and although it is supplied with 10 V, when I increase the position of its potentiometer, it works fine without lack of sound and excess heat generation.

What could be the problem with the circuitry?

Comment: Can you share your layout? I’m concerned the tda chips might not be well decoupled and are oscillating.

Comment: What heatsinking do you have on the power amps? Were you intending to use them as bridge mode amps? That doesn't look much like bridge mode to me... Are they putting DC across the speakers?

Comment: What's up with the capacitors on the inverting inputs? You show one 10uF capacitor across the inputs and one to ground from one of them, the schematics I see in the datasheet and online show a 100uF cap from each to ground. I'm wondering if that is causing it to oscillate.

Comment: @Bryan Oh, the layout... It is literally a cable mess. Nevertheless, I am going to add it to the post.

Comment: @user_1818839 As per the STMicroelectronics datasheet, mine is configured as the bridge mode because I am not using the sound system in stereo mode. Also, there is no heat sink just as in the case of the amplifier in my desktop loudspeaker system which has no problem like overheating.

Comment: @GodJihyo I've implemented the system on that bridge test circuit in the datasheet.

Comment: Sounds like HF oscillation dominates the circuit. To me once helped a series resistor directly at the input. Together with the input capacitance of the circuit this formed a low pass filter and stopped the oscillation. I just don't remember the value, something between 10 and 100k.

Comment: @Jens This can be the main issue as in the stereo desktop loudspeaker circuit of Samsung, there was an RC network just before the each input which was accomplished with a 22K resistor in series with a 1uF capacitor which is followed by a 6.2K resistor that is shunted between the input and ground. But, I am scared of interfering with the filter network that comes before those amplifiers. May this remedy cause a critical problem?

Comment: @Karakoncolos Okay, I see it now. Never mind.

Comment: @Karakoncolos: Yes, 22k, that was it! I don't think there will be an impact in the filter stage.

Comment: Do the math! Of course 6k2 shunting 22k raises the filter bandwidth to 0.16/RC with the lower R.  Fix your layout wiring with magnet wire twisted pairs on bottom . AWG30 and shunt some unused pads to gnd for a ground plane to input gnd.

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is inefficiency induced heat rise. The schematic shows 4 to 8 ohms making the impedance mismatch uncertain.
The datasheet shows 32 Ohm is optimal for 9V and lower impedance speakers demand lower supply voltage.

this is simply due to impedance matching and not following the datasheet on the OP's part and being unclear about which speaker was used and what power was being drawn to cause the apparent problem.

Ohm's Law will explain.

- the output voltage drop from each supply rail is given at only 5 mA max as 1.5V & 1V for each driver in differential output. thus 18V-5V= 13Vpp but more likely 12Vpp max
- 6V/4 Ohms is 1.5A pp.
- Ohms Law means the 5V drop x1.5A is 7.5Watts peak maximum at full power into a chip that is happy with dissipating 0.5W

### do you see the problem yet?

- The speaker choice is mismatched to the voltage. either riase to 32
  Ohms or Lower supply to 5V then 2Vac/4 Ohms is 0.5App and this is
  also 1W . using more supply like 6V is possible then 6-2.5V = 3.5V

Other risks are Oscillations result when parasitic shunt capacitance with series inductance couples to non-inverting inputs with positive feedback (PFB) gain >1 then...

That results in full power dissipation with inadequate heatsinks resulting in high temperatures.

Examine your ground noise, long wires that parallel to PFB high impedance inputs.  Gnd is supposed to be 0V. Or is it xx mVac?  Use wide busbar or braid for gnds. Same for V+'S and decoupling caps must be low ESR.

The RC snubbers seem to be insufficient load to reduce to RF output >> 20 kHz  Try 2 Ohms and compute C accordingly. Try NFB , same and wire neatly to avoid long wires in high current loops that are not using twisted pairs to cancel inductive EMI at RF.  Compute 10 nH / cm impedance at measure RF oscillations for output stage and PFB inputs. Use AWG 30 Magnet wire twisted pairs for critical I/O's.

- always use short gnd clips for 10:1 probes if noise > 10 MHz.

IF THERE ARE NO OSCILLATIONS > 20kHz then it is a simple Thermal problem with high thermal resistance. e.g. > 50'C / Watt

### Suggestion

With 10V AND 4 Ohms load, you can imagine 50% of 25 Watts being shared somewhere.  To reduce heat rise to +25'C max that means you need to sink 1 watt/1'C rise which is a large heatsink. Since Class A is low efficiency.

The datasheet shows a 10 cm^2 heatsink ground plane and only 1.5W Max in free air and 4W max with large heatsink.

Stick a heatsink or Alum plate 3x3cm on IC with 3M thermal tape or equiv.

[image]

Comment: There are so many things to consider. In my desktop sound system, there was a cable battle too but not that much in that problematic circuit. Usage of PCB seems a good idea in coping with those unintentional effects. Thanks for caring the post.

Comment: Can you measure current and compute watts?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to do so at this moment as I've tested the system in my university's lab. But, according to the datasheet of TDA2822M and my calculations, the output power is not stretching beyond 3 W. I am planning to build up a test circuit on which I will do some changes on the signal input and output of the amplifiers.

Comment: Certainly have a thermal problem because as I said it is only rated for 1.5 watts without a copper ground plane or a heatsink which is clearly written in the datasheet

Comment: Even that might be too hot to touch and hold 55'C . Learn to measure T on case and hottest lead and compare with   Rja Rca Rjc for jcn. Case, ambient

Comment: The messy tangle of wires all over the place is causing capacitive positive feedback coupling causing high frequency oscillation. An LM58 is never used fir audio because it produces crossover distortion, hiss noise and has a poor slew rate cutting high audio frequencies.

Comment: @Audioguru do U still think it is oscillations at low power when cool?

Comment: The obsolete 8-pins TDA2822M power amplifier is using a 10V supply which is higher than the datasheet specs. It is rated for a 6V max supply with an 8 ohm speaker or a 4.5V max supply with a 4 ohm speaker. It will be very hot when the tangled mess of wires all over the place causes it to oscillate.

Comment: @Audioguru  Obsolete part is irrelevant. Your specs are incorrect and you didn't answer my question? when input was low level

Comment: Maybe the TDA2822M is obsolete because some or all of then had a problem with over-heating?

Comment: @Audioguru of course cost / performance for a 1W output and 0.5W chip at 50 cents (100pc)  is now replaced by a 1A audio chip https://resources.kitronik.co.uk/pdf/2944_njm2073d_datasheet.pdf  You still ignored my question of oscillations and stability vs audio output current. How likely is that?

Comment: Since the volume controls at the input of the power amplifiers can be turned down to zero then at zero setting there is unlikely a chance for oscillation. Due to overheating, the little TDA2822M and the little Japanese copy overheat and are not spec'd to use a power supply higher than 6V with an 8 ohm speaker or 4.5V with a 4 ohm speaker.

Comment: @Audioguru The desktop loudspeaker system uses a TDA2822M which is driving a 4 ohm speaker and operated at approximately 9 V of supply voltage and there is no problem like excessive heating. Apparently, the problem is about the configuration of the layout.

Comment: The problems is as I stated , what have you done to fix it?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I haven't tried out the possible remedies as I am busy right now. When I do so, I will leave a comment. Thanks again.

Comment: If course the amount of heating depends on the output power (volume level) and type of music if the IC is not oscillating. The datasheet shows the amount of heating at full output power without clipping.